# Symfony 3 Quiz project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new in Symfony framework. I want to do a simple quiz with questions and few answers for them. My problem is to display only one question and answers for it. When I try it it shows me dropdown list of questions and all answers from all questions.

My database is:

```
questions:
  - id PK
  - question
answers:
  - id PK
  - answer
choices:
  - id PK
  - questions_id FK
  - answers_id FK
  - isCorrect
```

QuizController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Questions;
use AppBundle\Entity\Answers;
use AppBundle\Entity\Choices;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Form\QuizType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class QuizController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/quiz", name="quiz_index")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
     public function formAction(Request $request)
     {
         $choice = new Choices();
         $form = $this->createForm(QuizType::class, $choice);

         return $this->render("Quiz/quiz.html.twig", ["form" => $form->createView()]);
     }
}
```

QuizType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Answers;
use AppBundle\Entity\Questions;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class QuizType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('question')
            ->add('answer', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Answers::class,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,))
            ->add("submit", SubmitType::class, ["label" => "Zapisz"]);
    }
}
```

quiz.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: As I see, you're using a many-to-many relationship, does each answer may be related to many questions, or one question have many answers and one answer belongs to one question?

Comment: It should be a second option: one question have many answers and one answer belongs to one question. So should i change my database structure?

Comment: Yes you should change it the schema above tells that you have a many-to-many relationshop, so you need to change it to one-to-many, the form will automatically shows you the answers related to that question form, and don't forget to add the "isCorrect" field on your answer entity

Comment: PS: Please avoid naming your entity classes in the plural (Answers => Answer), you're working with objects with type of Answer

Comment: Thanks for advice about naming. Unfortunately, when I deleted table "choices" and changed relation of "answers" and "questions", my form shows me all answers from all questions.